# Unable to delete eSIM profile on Google Pixel 3a

Tags: sim-card, google-pixel, esim

I have recently changed phone carriers. I cannot download an eSIM for my new carrier while it is supposed to be compatible with the Pixel 3a. They claim this is because I still have the eSIM profile from my previous carrier. For some reason, I cannot erase this old eSIM profile manually. I get the following error message: “Can't erase SIM. This SIM can't be erased due to an error. Restart your device and try again.” Of course, I still can't erase the eSIM when I restart the phone.

I have contacted both carriers, as well as Google. They had me reset Wi-Fi, mobile & Bluetooth which didn't work. The next step they advise is a factory reset. I'd like to find another way to erase this faulty eSIM profile and I'm not completely sure that a factory reset would be “strong enough” actually.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem or knows a way to force the deletion of the old eSIM profile?

Edit: as Robert suggested I have checked the device log. Here is the result:

```
12-25 19:36:01.101  2463  2463 I Showing dialog with title = %s: Effacer ce profil SIM téléchargé ?
12-25 19:36:01.145  1770  1921 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.android.settings/.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity: +122ms
12-25 19:36:01.200  2463  2463 W Choreographer: Frame time is 0.220733 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
12-25 19:36:01.200  2247  2247 W Choreographer: Frame time is 0.220733 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
12-25 19:36:01.560  1770  3866 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
12-25 19:36:01.577  1770  3866 I WifiService: startScan uid=1000
12-25 19:36:02.188  2463  2463 I DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity: Subscription deletion confirmed
12-25 19:36:02.188  2463  2463 V SidecarFragment: SidecarFragment.setState(): Sidecar Class: com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionSidecar, State: State.RUNNING, Substate.UNUSED
12-25 19:36:02.189  2463  2463 I DeleteEuiccSubscriptionSidecar: Deleting subscription ID: 3
12-25 19:36:02.192  2463  2539 D OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x70de910f50 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x6fee8d2fd0
12-25 19:36:02.193  2457  2941 D TelephonyProvider: Using old permission behavior for telephony provider compat
12-25 19:36:02.193  1770  3866 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'd46f1bc com.android.settings/com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
12-25 19:36:02.210  2662  2662 I EuiccGoogle: [2] EuiccServiceImpl.onCreate: onCreate DSDS mode: simCardState is 0
12-25 19:36:02.217  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscription: onDeleteSubscription: delete slotId = -1, iccId = 89330120209449770550
12-25 19:36:02.218  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.lockWriteLock: Successfully grant SIM state write lock
12-25 19:36:02.218  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive: ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive: slotId = -1, forceDeactivateSim = true
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive: Passed in slotId=-1; euiccIsActive=false; targetSlotIsRemovable=false; forceDeactivateSim=true.
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive: Multiple active slots supported, but slotId -1 is not active
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle: com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at com.google.android.flib.log.Blog.wtf(Blog.java:157)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at com.google.android.euicc.logging.EuiccGoogleLog.wtf(EuiccGoogleLog.java:20)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at com.android.euicc.service.EuiccServiceImpl.ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive(EuiccServiceImpl.java:3747)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at com.android.euicc.service.EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscriptionInternal(EuiccServiceImpl.java:1676)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at com.android.euicc.service.EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscription(EuiccServiceImpl.java:1640)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at android.service.euicc.EuiccService$IEuiccServiceWrapper$9.run(EuiccService.java:815)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
12-25 19:36:02.221  2662 10194 E EuiccGoogle:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
12-25 19:36:02.229  1770 10195 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=system_app_wtf isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
12-25 19:36:02.229  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscriptionInternal: onDeleteSubscriptionInternal: slotId = -1, iccId = 89330120209449770550, ensureSlotIsEuiccAndActive = Pair{131083 false}.
12-25 19:36:02.229  1770 10195 W DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: system_app_wtf (1306 > 0 bytes)
12-25 19:36:02.229  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscriptionInternal: onDeleteSubscriptionInternal: slotCheckResult = 131083
12-25 19:36:02.230  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.unlockWriteLock: SIM state write lock is locked by the current thread. Unlock it.
12-25 19:36:02.230  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccErrorMapper.mapErrorCode: Mapping for error code: 131083
12-25 19:36:02.231  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccErrorMapper.mapErrorCode: Mapping error code: 131083 to: 33554432
12-25 19:36:02.231  2662 10194 I EuiccGoogle: [67] EuiccServiceImpl.onDeleteSubscription: onDeleteSubscription errorCode: 131083, mapped to: 33554432
12-25 19:36:02.242  2463  2463 I EuiccOperationSidecar: Result code : 2; detailed code : 0
12-25 19:36:02.242  2463  2463 E DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity: Failed to delete the subscription.
12-25 19:36:02.242  2463  2463 V SidecarFragment: SidecarFragment.setState(): Sidecar Class: com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionSidecar, State: State.INIT, Substate.UNUSED
12-25 19:36:02.242  2463  2463 V SidecarFragment: SidecarFragment.setState(): Sidecar Class: com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionSidecar, State: State.INIT, Substate.UNUSED
12-25 19:36:02.246  3829  3829 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3301 
12-25 19:36:02.246  3829  3829 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1979 
12-25 19:36:02.247  3829  3829 I DeviceUnlockedTag: DeviceUnlockedTag.notifyDeviceLockStatusChanged():79 Notify device unlocked.
12-25 19:36:02.909  2463  2539 D OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x70de8e37e0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x6fee8db040
12-25 19:36:02.910  1770  3246 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '7633076 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
12-25 19:36:02.950  2463  2463 D NetworkSettings: onResume() subId=3
12-25 19:36:02.974  2457  2941 D TelephonyProvider: Using old permission behavior for telephony provider compat
12-25 19:36:02.999  2457  2941 D TelephonyProvider: Using old permission behavior for telephony provider compat
12-25 19:36:03.012  3829  3829 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3301 
12-25 19:36:03.013  3829  3829 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1979 
12-25 19:36:03.013  3829  3829 I DeviceUnlockedTag: DeviceUnlockedTag.notifyDeviceLockStatusChanged():79 Notify device unlocked.
12-25 19:36:03.049  1770  3246 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'a5961ab com.android.settings/com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
12-25 19:36:03.057  1770  3246 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '15c0fa7 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.network.telephony.DeleteEuiccSubscriptionDialogActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
12-25 19:36:03.928  1770  2180 D ConnectivityService: NetReassign [no changes]
```

Sorry for the log length, I can't really find where the problem is. From what I understand, it has to do with eUICC. I would bet the old carrier has messed up with permissions, but I can't be sure. Hopefully, someone may be able to identify the problem.

Comment: Enable developer options and check the device log via `adb logcat` while you are trying to delete the eSIM profile. Hopefully logcat will show an error message that helps you to understand what is going wrong.